# StackOverflowError when including Spring Boot Actuator as a dependency within the project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'm currently running a Spring Cloud Streams project in version `Greenwich.SR2`. Just tried to include the following dependency within the project.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But as soon as I include it and run the project, the following pops up.

```
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/sample/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.11.2/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.11.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/sample/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocator.getCallerClass(StackLocator.java:108)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocator.getCallerClass(StackLocator.java:121)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocatorUtil.getCallerClass(StackLocatorUtil.java:55)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
```

The set of dependencies regarding Spring Boot are the following ones.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I already have `.properties` files for `log4j2`, is the Actuator dependency using older or any other version of the one which is already included?

Comment: Did you exclude logback?

Comment: @spencergibb tried it yeah, but no luck so far.

Comment: Can you include the boot version and try updating to latest Greenwich.SR4?